# Thymeleaf internationalization in large text templates

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

In Thymeleaf, I have used templates such as

```html
... large text <span the:text="${someImportantNumber}"><span> large text <span the:text="${someImportantNumber2}"><span> large text ...
```

Now I want to internationalize this. What is the best way to do that? I am asking because I have found that this is usually done by inserting a text with variables into messages_XX.properties, e.g.

```
some.key=This is a large text with important numbers: {0} and {1} and then there is lot's of text again with many other variables .. {100}
```

and then insert the variables on the go inside the th:text attribute.

```
<span th:text="#{some.key(${someImportantNumber}, ${someImportantNumber2},...,${someImportantNumber100})}"></span>
```

Is this really the way to go for very large texts? How is it usually done in the industry?